# Kotlin coroutines unit testing using mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, kotlinx.coroutines

i am getting the below when i try to mock and verify on an activity that's calling a suspend function

**Error:**

Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
userManager.getAccountInfo(
(onCreate_callsGetAccountInformation$1) kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.CoroutineScope.() -> kotlin.Unit
);
-> at com.pharmacy.AccountActivityTests$onCreate_callsGetAccountInformation$1.doResume(AccountActivityTests.kt:117)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
userManager.getAccountInfo(
() kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.CoroutineScope.() -> kotlin.Unit
)
-> at com.pharmacy.AccountActivity$loadAccountInfoAsync$1$1.doResume(AccountActivity.kt:199)

**Code:**

I have my unit test case decorated with runBlocking like this:

```
    @Test 
    fun onCreate_callsGetAccountInformation() = runBlocking<Unit> 
    { whenever(userManager.getAccountInfo()).thenReturn(AccountInformation()) 
      subject = Robolectric.setupActivity(AccountActivity::class.java) 
      verify(userManager).getAccountInfo() 
    }
```

here -> usermanager.getAccountInfo() is a suspend function.

Answer (score 1):

It was the mockito version, 2.10 and below does not support suspend functions.  bumping it to latest(2.12) fixed it.